# xkb mapping of R_Control+Arrows

Tags: 17.10, keyboard-layout, xkb

Have a laptop with directional Arrow keys and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + Arrows for <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>/<kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>. Want to make those keys such that the Right Control changes them to:

- <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> -> <kbd>Page Up</kbd>
- <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> -> <kbd>Page Down</kbd>
- <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd>
- <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

Left control should continue to work as before.

### XKB that is close to working:

The following content is saved to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom` and loaded via this command `setxkbmap -symbols "pc+us+inet(evdev)+custom"`:

```
key <UP> {  
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]= [ Up, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<PGUP>, clearMods=Control)] };  
key <DOWN> {  
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]= [ Down, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<PGDN>, clearMods=Control)] };  
key <LEFT> {  
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]=  [ Left, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<PGUP>)] };  
key <RGHT> {   
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]= [ Right, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<PGDN>)] };
```

### The Problem:

Unfortunately the script above captures both Control keys, not only the right one. I need the left <kbd>Control</kbd> key to not change it's behavior. Changing the *PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2* -> *PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2* looks like it should work, but nothing works differently in that case (as if I hadn't made any changes).

Any ideas why PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2 doesn't do anything?

I have tried bumbling around all sorts of different things, but unfortunately nothing has worked. I can't even seem to keep the right control key from acting as a control key, even after trying to map it directly to another key.

I am currently running Ubuntu 17.10 w/ the default GNOME interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.  I will discuss them first and then
give three solutions, all of which work in my tests.

**Issue A:**  The "dangling virtual modifier" bug in xkb configs.

Notice that `type "PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2"`
(defined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types/pc`)
uses the virtual modifier `RControl`.  For the virtual modifier
`RControl` to do what we expect,
it should be associated with the actual keysym `Control_R` via an
`interpret` stanza in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/pc`.  But the
virtual modifier `RControl` is not associated with any keysym at all,
and in fact it is not set up in any way in the compatibility configs:
`grep RControl /usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/*` returns nothing.
This is why you are finding that `PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2` has no effect,
and this can be considered to be a "dangling `RControl` config bug"
in xkb.
(This issue does not affect the type `PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2` because
that type does not use any virtual modifier - it uses the
real modifier `Control`.)

**Issue B:**  Need a separate real modifier bit for right control,
distinct from the `Control` modifier bit.

The symbols config file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` contains:

```
modifier_map Control { Control_L, Control_R };
```

As the left and right control keys
are both configured by default to set the `Control` modifier bit,
they will behave identically unless explicitly bound to distinct
modifier bits via separate modifier maps.
Here we of course need the right control key to act as a
different modifier than the left control key.
This can be done, e.g., by changing the right control key's
modifier bit (`Control`) to a different available modifier bit,
say `Mod3` (`Mod3` is not bound to any key in the
default xkb configs).

Here are three ways to address these two issues.

**Solution 1:
Fix the dangling virtual modifier issue for `RControl`**.

The workaround below achieves your desired setup (in my tests).

First, include the following in your xkb compatibility configs
to interpret the `Control_R` keysym as the virtual modifier
`RControl`:

```
partial default xkb_compatibility "rctrlinterpret" {

  virtual_modifiers RControl;

  interpret Control_R+Any {
    virtualModifier = RControl;
    useModMapMods= level1;
    action= SetMods(modifiers=RControl, clearLocks);
  };

  interpret Control_R {
    virtualModifier = RControl;
    action= SetMods(modifiers=RControl, clearLocks);
  };

};
```

(E.g., you can save the above to a file, say `rctrlfix`, and then
within `xkb_compat { ... }`, change the `include "complete"` to
`include "complete+rctrlfix"`.)

Next, separate the modifier map for the right control key.
Since its existing modifier map in the default config uses the
keysym `Control_R`, you will need to use the keysym `Control_R`
when replacing the modifier map; using the key `<RCTL>`
will not work.
You will also need to manually clear and set desired modifier bits
in your key emulations.
So include the following in your symbols configs:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "rctrlarrows" {

    replace key <RCTL> { [ Control_R ] };    // The default, anyway

    // Bind to modifier Mod3 (instead of existing default Control)
    replace modifier_map none { Control_R };
    replace modifier_map Mod3 { <RCTL> };

    key <UP> {
        type = "PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2",
        symbols = [ Up, NoSymbol ],
        actions = [ NoAction(),
                        RedirectKey(
                            key=<PGUP>,
                            clearMods=RControl
                        )]
    };

    key <DOWN> {
        type = "PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2",
        symbols = [ Down, NoSymbol ],
        actions = [ NoAction(),
                        RedirectKey(
                            key=<PGDN>,
                            clearMods=RControl
                        )]
    };

    key <LEFT> {
        type= "PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2",
        symbols = [ Left, NoSymbol ],
        actions = [ NoAction(),
                        RedirectKey(
                            key=<PGUP>,
                            clearMods=RControl,
                            Modifiers=Control
                    )]
    };


    key <RGHT> {
        type= "PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2",
        symbols = [ Right, NoSymbol ],
        actions = [ NoAction(),
                        RedirectKey(
                            key=<PGDN>,
                            clearMods=RControl,
                            Modifiers=Control
                        )]
    };

};
```

As the modifier map for `Control_R` is being defined a second time,
there can be a error message saying that, but it seems harmless.

A variant of Solution 1 would be to ditch the keysym `Control_R`
altogether, and use a spare keysym in its place that is not a
modifier and not used in the compatibility configs (e.g. `Pause`),
and interpret it as the virtual modifier `RControl` in the
compatibility configs.  That is, replace `Control_R` by `Pause`
throughout in the above configs.  This would also avoid the
multiple modifier map error message.

**Alternative workarounds.**

**Solution 2:
Bypass the dangling virtual modifier issue by using a type
based on a real modifier (`Mod3`)**.

If the symbols configs are customized as above with `Mod3`
being the real modifier bit for the keysym `Control_R`
(key `<RCTL>`), then the same result can be achieved
by modifying the types configs (instead of modifying
the compatibility configs, which can be left untouched):
In the type definition of `PC_RCONTROL_LEVEL2`,
replace the virtual modifier `RControl` by the
real modifier `Mod3`.
(You may want to put this in a new type, and in your key
emulations change the type names accordingly.)

**Solution 3: Re-define `<RCTL>` as the level 3 shifter keysym
`ISO_Level3_Shift`**.

Still another workaround (without need to touch either the
compatibility configs or the types configs) would be to
re-define the `<RCTL>` key as the Level3 modifier keysym
`ISO_Level3_Shift` (instead of `Control_R`).  Then
define your desired key emulations using `type = "THREE_LEVEL"`
and with symbol/action values defined at the third level
(instead of the second level).  This will work as expected,
since (a) the default xkb symbols configs define a "fake" key
`<LVL3>` as the keysym `ISO_Level3_Shift` with the real
modifier bit `Mod5` bound to it via a modifier map,
(b) the default xkb types configs define the
type `THREE_LEVEL`'s level 3 shifting using the virtual modifier
`LevelThree`, and (c) the default xkb compatibility configs
interpret the keysym `ISO_Level3_Shift` as the
virtual modifier `LevelThree`, so there is no dangling
virtual modifier issue.

```
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "rctrlarrows" {

    replace key <RCTL> {
        type[Group1] = "ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
    };
    // Keysym ISO_Level3_Shift is bound to the real modifier bit Mod5
    // in the xkb default configs in symbols/pc (via key <LVL3>)

    key <UP>  { 
        type    =   "THREE_LEVEL",
        symbols =   [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol ],
        actions =   [ NoAction(), NoAction(),
                        RedirectKey(keycode=<PGUP>,
                            clearmods=LevelThree)
                    ]
    };

    key <DOWN>  {
        type    =   "THREE_LEVEL",
        symbols =   [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol ],
        actions =   [ NoAction(), NoAction(),
                        RedirectKey(keycode=<PGDN>,
                            clearmods=LevelThree)
                    ]
    };

    key <LEFT>  {
        type    =   "THREE_LEVEL",
        symbols =   [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol ],
        actions =   [ NoAction(), NoAction(), 
                        RedirectKey(keycode=<PGUP>,
                            modifiers=Control, clearmods=LevelThree)
                    ]
    };

    key <RGHT>  {
        type    =   "THREE_LEVEL",
        symbols =   [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol ],
        actions =   [ NoAction(), NoAction(),
                        RedirectKey(keycode=<PGDN>,
                            modifiers=Control, clearmods=LevelThree)
                    ]
    };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a function wrapper as follows.

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "custom" {

key <UP> {  
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]= [ Up, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<PGUP>, clearMods=Control)] };  
key <DOWN> {  
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]= [ Down, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<PGDN>, clearMods=Control)] };  
key <LEFT> {  
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]=  [ Left, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<PGUP>)] };  
key <RGHT> {   
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",  
    symbols[Group1]= [ Right, NoSymbol ],  
    actions[Group1] = [NoAction(), RedirectKey(key=<PGDN>)] };
};
```